# How can I assign data from received data in VueJS?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

How can I assign data from received data?
my code is below. axios is working well. I can get response.data from server . and I tried to assign the data to imglists variable. but It doesn't assign. What's wrong with me? Is There something wrong?
please help me out.

```
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',  
  data: {      
    imglists: [],  
  },  
  created(){     
      axios.post('https://test.com/hello-lambda')
   .then(function (response) {        
     this.imglists = response.data;
   }).catch(function (error) {    
    console.log(error);  
   });  
}})
```

Comment: `this` is not what you think it is in the callback. Use arrow functions: `.then((response) => { `

Answer (score 1):

In the example code above `this` is bound to the created function. To bind this to the object context, you'll need a function that doesn't bind `this`. Use [ES6(ES2015)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) to solve the binding issue.

Use the ES6 syntax:

```
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',  
  data: {      
    imglists: [],  
  },  
  created(){     
      axios.post('https://test.com/hello-lambda')
       .then(response =>  this.imglists = response.data)
       .catch(error =>console.log(error));  
  }
})
```

Comment: I changed my code like this. Thank you. it's working.

Answer (score 1):

Your reference to **this** is scoped to the function it is inside of so you need to create an external reference.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Also data should be a returned object to create a reactive object to trigger re-renders (nextTick) when the data is changed in **imagelists** due to this usage case being an asynchronous call.

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Async-Update-Queue

```
var app = new Vue({

  el: '#app',

  data: () => ({
    imglists: []
  }),

  created(){

    let self = this;

    axios.post('https://test.com/hello-lambda').then(response => {  
  
        self.imglists = response.data;

   }).catch(error => {    
     console.log(error);  
   });  

}})
```

The var **self** and function **then()** plus its own content is scoped to function **created()** allowing child functions access to vars declared at the top level (parent function or script file) but be mindful if 'strict mode' is enforced as this will change the behavior of scoping / inheritance.